# Symfony 2 Rest api

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I created a simple REST service based on Symfony 2 and FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle. The GET request work well but I have a problem with POST.

I used this tutorial:

```
http://npmasters.com/2012/11/25/Symfony2-Rest-FOSRestBundle.html
```

When I send request looks like it was not getting attributes. I have response message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO article (title, content, category_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null
```

I use curl like this:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"title":"aaa","content":"asdasdasdasd","category":1}'  http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/v1/articles.json --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was badly formatted json. Should be:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"article":{"title":"aaa","content":"asdasdasdasd","category":1}}'  http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/v1/articles.json --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```